# What is proper edge coloring and how to show it?

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning

> Show  that  in  any  proper  edge  coloring  of K5,  no  color  can 
>   occur  more  than twice.  (show that four colors could not be enough
>   for a proper edge coloring of K 5).

Could someone explain to me, with the example of a **graph** for example, how to do this? I don't understand what they mean with *"proper edge coloring"*.

My own thought was: we have a complete graph with 5 *vertices*, so we have either 4 or 5 as the `chromatic number`.

Yet I need a confirmation of what I am doing and if I am doing and thinking correctly. Could someone help me with this?

I want to understand it and need an example to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $K_5$ is always the complete graph with five *vertices*.

However the *coloring* we're talking about here is an **edge coloring** -- in other words, you assign a color to each edge instead of to each vertex. The coloring is "proper" if edges that share an endpoint have different colors.

For example, here is $K_4$:

```
O--O
|\/|
|/\|
O--O
```

This graph has a proper edge coloring with $3$ colors: For example color the two vertical edges red, the horizontal edges green, and the diagonals blue.

Comment: instead of to each edge ?? ... do you mean ... instead of to each vertex ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit: Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that in a proper edge coloring of $K_5$, no color can be assigned to $3$ or more edges.

Two edges are said to be *adjacent* (or *incident*) in $G=(V,E)$ if they have an endpoint in common and are said to be *independent* otherwise.   Given a graph $G$, a proper edge coloring of $G$ is an assignment of colors to edges which satisfies the condition that adjacent edges are assigned different colors.  This implies that in a proper edge coloring of $G$, each *color class* (ie the set of edges which are assigned the same color) is a set of independent edges.

Now, if a color class has $k$ edges, since no two of these $k$ edges share a common endpoint, the number of vertices incident to these $k$ edges is exactly $2k$.  Thus, if a color class has size $3$, the graph must contain at least $6$ vertices.  However, $K_5$ has only $5$ vertices and so cannot contain a set of $3$ independent edges. Hence, in any proper edge coloring of $K_5$, no color class has size more than $2$.